# Migrate database from MySQL to PostgreSQL via Pgloader in Cent OS

Tags: mysql, database, macos, postgresql, centos

I'm very confused, and don't understand how this has happened. I used [pgloader](http://pgloader.io/) in my Mac OS X to migrate data from MySQL to PostgreSQL database.

## Mac OSX

I tried

`pgloader mysql://root@localhost/local postgresql://postgres@localhost/portal`

I got

```
2016-06-15T13:11:23.017000-07:00 LOG Main logs in '/private/tmp/pgloader/pgloader.log'
2016-06-15T13:11:23.060000-07:00 LOG Data errors in '/private/tmp/pgloader/'
2016-06-15T13:11:23.262000-07:00 WARNING PostgreSQL warning: table "mirror_settings" does not exist, skipping
            table name       read   imported     errors            time
----------------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------
       fetch meta data         25         25          0          0.092s
          create, drop          0         26          0          0.217s
----------------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------
                caches          1          1          0          0.156s
       captive_portals          5          5          0          0.074s
              captures          2          2          0          0.029s
      cloud_securities          7          7          0          0.024s
               devices         88         88          0          0.056s
             externals          1          1          0          0.018s
            migrations         52         52          0          0.028s
       mirror_settings          1          1          0          0.036s
         notifications          7          7          0          0.038s
             operators          1          1          0          0.014s
            promotions          5          5          0          0.015s
                 users        224        224          0          0.020s
              visitors         14         14          0          0.013s
Index Build Completion          0          0          0          0.020s
----------------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------
        Create Indexes         12         12          0          0.124s
       Reset Sequences          0         11          0          0.012s
          Primary Keys         11         11          0          0.009s
          Foreign Keys          0          0          0          0.000s
              Comments          0          0          0          0.000s
----------------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  --------------
     Total import time        408        408          0          0.871s
```

All tables, and data in within them are imported **perfectly**.

---

## Cent OS 6.7 (64 bits)

Then, I've SSH into my local VM as root@172.16.139.1 and run

`pgloader mysql://root@172.16.139.1/local postgresql://postgres@172.16.139.130/portal`

I got

```
debugger invoked on a SIMPLE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10070AB033}>:
  Error opening shared object "libssl.so.1.0.0":
  libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE       ] Skip this shared object and continue.
  1: [RETRY          ] Retry loading this shared object.
  2: [CHANGE-PATHNAME] Specify a different pathname to load the shared object from.

(SB-SYS:DLOPEN-OR-LOSE #S(SB-ALIEN::SHARED-OBJECT :PATHNAME #P"libssl.so.1.0.0" :NAMESTRING "libssl.so.1.0.0" :HANDLE NIL :DONT-SAVE NIL))
0] 0
An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   The value NIL
   is not of type
     (OR (VECTOR CHARACTER) (VECTOR NIL) BASE-STRING PATHNAME STREAM).

; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 1 fatal ERROR condition
```

Comment: Wait, my first command, I ran it in my Mac and pointing it to my VM that is also host by my Mac. I don't think I have installed any kinds of SSL for my local VM. Are you sure ? Plus, how do I install libssl ? I hope you don't mind .

Comment: I don't think I purchased or enable any kind of SSL on my local VM. I'm not saying that you're wrong because even me I am not sure. How do check to see if my local VM has SSL enabled/installed.

Comment: *Note*: the issue is happening when I ssh into my local linux cent OS VM. The issue is not happening on my Mac.

Comment: I tried `brew install ssl` on my Mac (Not sure why I need to do that) - But I got `Warning: openssl-1.0.2h_1 already installed`

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused too. You are seeing the error only when you execute the pgloader command in centos but not on your mac?

Comment: BTW, how did you install pgloader from yum or from source?

Comment: `wget http://pgsql.tapoueh.org/pgloader/pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm` then
`rpm -i pgloader-3.0.98-21.el6.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: I'm stuck on this error `libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a corrupt pgloader installation. The download link on http://tapoueh.org/pgloader/download.html from which you appeared to have grabbed the RPM is for Centos 6.4 unfortunately a lot has changed since then.

I recommend that you try the official postgresql [YUM repository](http://yum.postgresql.org/news-packagelist.php). Please uninstall the previously installed RPM before you do so. However even this repository has marked pgloader as not fully compatible. So if this option fails you will have no choice but to compile from source.

Comment: Thanks for your details answered.

Comment: No, it's not working. I have 6.7 and I use the one for 6.4. I'm not sure what to do now, I created issues on  pgloader git hub site. I hope they have some hints for me.

Comment: Which one did you try? Installing from the postgresql YUM repo or the source install?

Comment: Yesterday, I tried cloning from the git hub [site](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader).

Comment: usually with yum install package .

Comment: Any other suggestions ?

Comment: yes you have to add the yum repo which is explained in the linked page

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to install from that yum repo

Comment: So I decide to write my own Pgloader

Comment: going through my old answers, came across this. So did you really end up writing your own loader?

Comment: Great to know. Hope you make it into a github project.